# How to use dynamic imports for redux 'actions' for bundle size optimisation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I am trying to optimise the initial page bundle size for an application. I am trying to defer loading the `firebase` bundle until I load a component that uses redux to make database calls.

Following is the actions file:

```js
import { DB } from '../../firebase/initialize';

export const addText = (text, callback) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_TEXT',
    status: 'started',
  });
  DB.collection('texts').then(() => {
    // Do something
  });
};
```

This is loading `firebase` which is loading approx `100KB` of code. I wanted to do load this code only after the site has completed loading.

So, I am lazy loading the component `TextList` that has dependency to `redux` action which uses `firebase` to get data. I was expecting this would make my `actions` and `firebase` be part of a different bundle created for `TextList` component and its dependency. But this is not the case.

```js
// import react and others
import configureStore from './redux/stores/store';
import Home from './components/molecules/home/home';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={configureStore()}>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Home />
    </Suspense>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```js
import React, { Component, lazy } from 'react';

const TextList = lazy(() => import('../../compounds/TextList/text-list'));

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home-page">
        <TextList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

And when `Home` loads, it loads redux actions at last:

```js
import React, { Component, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as actions from '../../../redux/actions/actions';

class TextList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSnippet();
  }
  render() {
    return // template
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(TextList);
```

What approach should I follow to lazy load `firebase` and component using the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic import for the firebase module in your actions file :shrug:

```
const getDB = async () => await import('../../firebase/initialize');

export const addText = (text, callback) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_TEXT',
    status: 'started',
  });
  const DB = await getDB();
  DB.collection('texts').then(() => {
    // Do something
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But this alone is not helping me. Webpack is still adding firebase to the bundle.